# How to pass jQuery boolean value to controller in MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have Model

```
public class ExampleModel
{
  public bool boolValue { get; set; }
}
```

jQuery like

```
...

var boolVal = $("#SomeId").val();

form = 'boolVal=' + boolVal;
...

somefunction()
{
   $("#SomeId").val(true) // assign true
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Edit(SomeCustomClass customClass)
{
  ...
  if(customClass.boolVal) // here I always gets false
  ...
}
```

View

```
@Html.Hidden("SomeId", new{@value = "false"})
```

What is the correct way to pass `true or false` to the controller? In my example I always get false.

TIA

Comment: Can you include slightly more information, such as the actionresult method signature and the way the information is posted (either from a submit button in html or a submit ajax call in script).

Comment: You have not provided enough code or information for an answer to be provided. I will tell you, though, that `.val()` will only return strings given it's reading from a value attribute.

Comment: either you use jquery ajax, or you submit the form with the same variable to the class of SomeCustomClass